# How do I fix "cannot find symbol - method java.lang.String

Tags: java, bluej

I am trying to make this code allow me to update fields in an access database but it keeps popping up with "cannot find symbol - method upDateChesney(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String

I have tried to rename the DataBase Handler but i am having no luck

```
         private void upDateFireplacesTable()
         {
             //Defining variables
             int code;


             //upDate Fireplaces will return a -1 if there is a problem
             code = DataBaseHandler.upDateChesney(ID, title, Supplier,price);

             //Check to see what code it contains
             if (code == -1) //Problem report an error
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (frame, "Problem updating record");
             }

             //if the update is successfull then the update method will return 1
             //(the total number of records updated)
             //which would always be 1 since I can only update one record at a time
             else if (code == 1)
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (frame, "Record successfully updated");
             }
```

//The one below is the database handler code

```
      static public int upDateFireplacesTable(String oldIDIn, String newIDIn,String titleIn,String SupplierIn, String priceIn)          
      {
               int code;  // This will hold the number of records affected by the
                          // executeUpDate() method which is used here to UPDATE

               // Build the SQL UPDATE string which involves updating a BOOK record
               String SQLString = "UPDATE FIREPLACES SET ID = '" + newIDIn + "', Title = '" + titleIn               
                                    + "', Supplier = '" + SupplierIn + "', price = " + priceIn +
                                    " WHERE ID = '" + oldIDIn + "'";

               // Update BOOK table
               try
               {
                    // The createStatement() method creates a Statement object.  
                    statement = ConnectionToChesneyDB.createStatement();

                    // executeUpdate() returns the number of records
                    // affected, in this case it will always be either 0 or
                    // 1 (since each book's isbn is unique)
                    code = statement.executeUpdate (SQLString);

                }
              catch (SQLException exception)
                {
                     return (-1);     // Return -1 if some kind of problem encountered

                }

            return (code);   // Return back with the number of records affected
                             // => 1 in this case.


        } // End upDateBook()
```

I want the code to be able to allow me to update existing records on the database

Comment: you need tell us where DataBaseHandler coming from? it is coming from library or you write it?  Anyway, debug will very easy.

Comment: Perhaps you can post the stack trace of the error?

Comment: I am quite new to this how would i find where it is coming from, I have a class called DataBaseHandler

Comment: How do i perform a stack trace?

Comment: Your method `upDateChesney()` must be static in class `DataBaseHandler`.  Is this the case?  Double check that your lower/upper case exactly matches.

Comment: I don't have a method of `upDateChesney()` in the DataBaseHandler. All I have is the `upDateFireplacesTable` method. How would i add the other method

Comment: How would you add it?..type it in?  Whenever you see the "cannot find symbol" error, it means the compiler can't find it.  This can be because it doesn't exist, or you typed it in wrong, or you have a case mismatch, etc.

Comment: Note that your existing upDateFireplacesTable() method accepts five strings, while the method upDateChesney() that you're trying to call accepts only four.

Comment: you should add the upDateChesney() method to the DatabaseHandler class